# JPA Hibernate: How to prevent join on retrieving?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

Suppose I have the following objects (one table per object) with this relations:
A -> B -> C -> D

If I findById an instance of A, all B, C and D are returned which is not I want. Is this possible to force Hibernate only to return A (or only it's primitive properties)?

I know that I can write `"SELECT a.x, a.y, a.z, ... FROM A"` and then manually put the result list of objects in A, but this is somewhat timely as I should manually fill all properties. I have also checked all [Hibernate query hints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#d0e801) but nothing related.

Mohsen

Comment: your general setting that is required in your mapping is fetch="join"?

Comment: I don't have hibernate-specific properties. My ManyToOne or OneToOne associations' fetch=FetchType.EAGER which is unavoidable because relations are not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a constructor for A which fills all fields except the ones you don't want to join, you could select like this:

```
SELECT NEW A(a.x, a.y, a.z) FROM A a
```

Comment: is this Hibernate specific feature or JPA's?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this way I should add a new constructor for each query which is a nightmare.

Comment: You can create one constructor with all fields, and fill the unwanted fields with NULL.

Answer (score 2):

select a from A a ?

also, how have you've mapped your relations? lazy="proxy" and fetch="join"?

Comment: setting lazy="proxy" and fetch="join" is global and affects all other queries. This is a single query requirement.

Comment: Use criteria API if you want to specify query custom fetchmodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify fetch="select" and lazy="true" in your mapping. Especially if your relations -> are lists.

Comment: I have object to object relation (no list: one to one or many to one, where A is many side). setting lazy or fetch is global and affects all other queries. This is a single query requirement.

Comment: if you use the criteria api you can specify the fetch type. I don't know how/if you can do this with hql.